# I get error when I use datetime format. Error : out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It doesn't give an error when I do it like below

```
declare @dd datetime = GETDATE()
 select @dd
```

I get an error when I give the date manually

```
 declare @dd datetime = '2023-08-25 13:03:28.573' 
 select @dd
```

error :

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

if i use datetime2 format i can assign value manually.

```sql
 declare @dd datetime2 = '2023-08-25 13:03:28.573' 
 select @dd
```

How can I run it as datetime?

```sql
 declare @dd datetime = '2023-08-25 13:03:28.573' 
 select @dd
```

result : 2023-08-25 13:03:28.573

Comment: What happens if you use an unambiguous format (regardless of language setting and data type) like `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnn)`?

Comment: [What date/time literal formats are LANGUAGE and DATEFORMAT safe in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166771/1186)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the dateformat you desire

```
set dateformat ymd;
```

maybe the default language for your db has different default dateformat

Comment: IMHO, it would be better to use an ISO 8601 date format as suggested in comments instead of setting dateformat so that the same code works for all clients.

Comment: @DanGuzman - `2023-08-25 13:03:28.573` is ISO 8601 format. Legacy `datetime` datatype still treats it as ambiguous though (but `datetime2` doesn't).  `YYYY-MM-DD` for date and `hh:mm:ss.sss` with omitted `T` are both valid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @MartinSmith, I should have called out ISO 8601 format with the `T` to designate the time element `2023-08-25T13:03:28.573`.

Comment: While this works in the simple case, it's not universal, since there are many places you can't use `SET`. It also might be quite intrusive to an entire codebase to pepper these `SET` statements everywhere you might use a date literal. If you're going to touch all those places, may as well touch them to change the literal to an unambiguous format.

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit `style` with [`Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles) to specify the format:

```
declare @dd datetime = Convert( DateTime, '2023-08-25 13:03:28.573', 121 );
select @dd;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0a1aNUbw).